# The force distribution inside a 3D body under the continuum hypothesis

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics

I am trying to make sense of the Cauchy stress tensor, and here is my motivational understanding of it. Please let me know if it is correct.

Under the continuum hypothesis, any body is decomposed on infinitesimal (cube) volumes. When an external force acts on the body, the force transfers through the body through infinitesimal volumes. So each infinitesimal cube will push the other cubes to "move forward". Now, assume there is a force where it directly touches one infinitesimal cube. Then this cube will push the next one in line and would "pull" with an angle the cubes below and above it. If we draw the field force acting on each infinitesimal volume, it will look like the one in the figure below.

[image]

Comment: Once the body is uniformly accelerating, the net force on every tiny cube must be the same -- $ma$ for the mass of the cube. What you're looking for is how that force is achieved -- through shear or compression or tension

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the area where your load is applied is small compared to the whole body, we can model this situation as a semi-infinite body with a point load on the surface. The lines of load are different from the ones that you are imagining.

The following image presents isocontours for the maximum stress and the lines for principal stresses. As you can see, they differ from your drawing.

[image]

I think that the main reason for the discrepancy, conceptually talking, is that the stress is not a vector quantity but a tensor one. Thus, you do not have a vector that describes it at each point.